# Calculating uncertainty when combining parallel resistors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrical-resistance, error-analysis

A recent question asks students to calculate the total resistance of parallel resistors R<sub>1</sub> and R<sub>2</sub> with uncertainty. R<sub>1</sub> = 120 Ω (+/-10%). R<sub>2</sub> = 500 Ω (+/-10%).

We would normally use the equation R = ( R<sub>1</sub><sup>-1</sup> + R<sub>2</sub><sup>-1</sup> )<sup>-1</sup>

The exam board's answer is 97 Ω (+/-10%). I understand the value for total resistance but can someone please give the simplest rule to explain the 10% uncertainty with some mathematical reasoning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The largest value of $R$ will be when $R_1$ and $R_2$ have their largest values. So putting $R_1= 132\ \Omega$ and $R_2= 550\ \Omega$, we get 106.5 $\Omega$, whereas if we put in the 'central' values, $R_1= 120\ \Omega$ and $R_2= 500\ \Omega$, we get 97 $\Omega$. The discrepancy as a percentage of 97 $\Omega$, is 10%.

The moral: elementary methods are sometimes the best! You *can* do this calculation by compounding individual uncertainties:

The percentage uncertainties in $\frac{1}{R_1}$ and $\frac{1}{R_2}$ are the same as in $R_1$ and $R_1$ because taking the reciprocal is a division. So, as Michael Seifert has calculated,$$G_1=\frac{1}{R_1}=(8.33±0.83)\times 10^{-3} \Omega^{-1}$$
$$G_2=\frac{1}{R_2}=(2.00±0.20)\times 10^{-3} \Omega^{-1}$$

We now have to *add* these conductances, so (in this naïve treatment) we add the *absolute* uncertainties. [We'd also add absolute uncertainties if we were subtracting quantities.]
$$\text{So}\ \ \ \ G=G_1+G_2=(10.33±1.03)\times 10^{-3} \Omega^{-1}$$

The percentage uncertainty in $G$ is therefore 10%. Taking the final reciprocal (a division operation) leaves the percentage uncertainty as 10%.
$$\text{So}\ \ \ \ R=\frac{1}{G}=(97±10) \Omega.$$

For divisions and multiplications you add percentage uncertainties, so if there is only one variable, as in $\frac{1}{R_1},$ the percentage uncertainty stays as it is. For quantities that are added or subtracted you add absolute uncertainties. For multiplication and division the addition of percentage uncertainties is, strictly, a first order approximation, but the whole treatment is oversimplified anyway (see M Seifert's answer).

Comment: So, is it always true that if an operation is performed on a variable (e.g. reciprocal) then that operation should be performed on the absolute uncertainty before combining with the uncertainties of other variables in an equation?

Comment: I don't think this is quite right, or I've misinterpreted it. The treatment I gave in the first para of my answer is what I'd advise A-level students to go for in a tricky case like this. I'm going to add to my answer to show how the "compounding uncertainties" method works, but I'm not recommending the method for this case. Note that both these treatments are naïve (but what A-level examiners expect); the other two answers are very instructive, but beyond the level needed at A-level

Comment: Thank you for expanding the 'naive' method. Our struggle was that we had several (incorrect) ways of getting to the correct answer but found it difficult to justify any of them mathematically. This has been most instructive. All for one mark in an AS exam!

Answer (score 2):

There is no mathematical reason to give a 10% percent error on the final resistance; there is, however, and engineering one.

First: If the percentage number encoded in the resistors' stripes were a 1-sigma Gaussian error, then @Michael Seifert's answer would be correct: add the resistors harmonically and the errors are reduced in quadrature.

But: Those number are not errors, they are tolerances. So $R=100\pm10\,\Omega$ is supposed to mean:

$$ R({\rm Ohm}) \in [90, 110] $$

In which case, @Philip Wood's answer is a better answer: to get the range, use the range.

But there is a problem: there are 5% and 1% resistors too. And they aren't included in the 10% stock. Hence, your 100 Ohm resistors exclude any ones that satisfies:

$$ R({\rm Ohm}) \in [95, 105] $$

which makes for bimodal input distributions (this is simply a terrible exam question, with a wrong answer, btw).

At this point, you have to Monte Carlo it, with the result that:

$$ R = 96.6\pm 6.2\,\Omega  $$

and

$$ 87 < R < 106.5 $$

See figure.

[image]

(note: a probability density per Ohm is in fact measured in Siemens ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the uncertainty if you carefully calculate things step by step.  The conductance $G = 1/R$ of each resistor is
$$
G_1 = \frac{1}{R_1} = (8.33 ± 0.83) \times 10^{-3} \, \mho 
$$ $$
G_2 = \frac{1}{R_2} = (2.00 ± 0.20) \times 10^{-3} \, \mho
$$
Note that the fractional uncertainties in the conductances are the same as those in the resistances (i.e., 10%).  From here, you can calculate the uncertainty in the total conductance $G_{eq} = G_1 + G_2$, and then calculate the uncertainty in the equivalent resistance.

As an aside:  if the uncertainties in the resistances are independent and uncorrelated, the uncertainty in $R_{eq}$ will actually be smaller than 10%, since the absolute uncertainties in $G_{eq}$ add in quadrature rather than directly.  Your students may or may not be expected to know this;  but if the given answer is 10%, I expect they're not expected to know it.